# Vba excel instr function with search string that ends with a unknown number

Tags: vba, excel

I want to search for a string that ends with a number but it is not known before what number it will be

So I'm using the InStr function

```
   InStr(Range("B" & row).Value), "text")
```

But now the problem is, what i'm searching for can be "text0", "text1", "text9", I don't want to create 10 times a Instr function to test al the 10 numbers.

What I'm looking for is a replacement character like you have # that stands for any given number in a input mask in Acces. So something like this

```
InStr(Range("B" & row).Value), "text" &  #)
```

offcoarse this will not work as excel will take this as search for "text#" and wil not interpretate it as # is any given number.

Edit:
Range("B" & row).Value will evaluate for example to "9S 279P3NOV/PDE NN1 PRS NO NVML"

What i need to know is where NN1 is so I can extract it.

But the next row can evaluate to "9S 2793NOV/PE NN12 REQ BANA"
So again I need to know where NN12 is, also notice the text before NN12 changes and that NN now has 2 digits.

Comment: look up [`Format()` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg251755(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: You need to test 10 numbers (0 to 9) or the number is random? Or the number is UserInput?

Comment: the number is random, the actual string i'm looking for always start with NN so the found string can be NN1, NN5 or actualy even NN25. There is no way in telling before what the number will be. And the number will never be higher than 2 digits neither there will be NN without number.

And format will format a string, how does that helps me?

Comment: And how do you get the number?

Comment: It comes from a export from AS400, the letters NN5 means normal 5 persons but the row where this information is in also contains a lot of other information including free userinput (but NN5 is not userinput). It is also not comma seperated and neither can I change the way the information comes in as it is a client who provides the sheet

Comment: Try the one liner I gave you `If stringToTest Like "NN*#"`

Comment: @RobinOvaere is the string always in form of NN##, where NN will never change, alwayrs followed by a number but the number is unknown?

Answer (score 5):

After reading the comments below the question

**the number is random, the actual string i'm looking for always start with NN so the found string can be NN1, NN5 or actualy even NN25. There is no way in telling before what the number will be.**

Is this what you are trying? Use the `LIKE` with wildcards.

Try this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim stringToTest(1 To 5) As String
    Dim i As Long

    stringToTest(1) = "Test01"
    stringToTest(2) = "Test01Test"
    stringToTest(3) = "123"
    stringToTest(4) = "01Test01"
    stringToTest(5) = "NNature1234"

    For i = 1 To 5
        If stringToTest(i) Like "NN*#" Then Debug.Print stringToTest(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

**Followup from comments / recent edit to the question**

If you format is going to as you have shown in the question, i.e there will be spaces then try this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim s As String, stringToTest(1 To 2) As String
    Dim ar
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    stringToTest(1) = "9S 279P3NOV/PDE NN1 PRS NO NVML"
    stringToTest(2) = "9S 2793NOV/PE NN12 REQ BANA"

    For i = 1 To 2
        s = stringToTest(i)
        If s Like "*NN*#*" And InStr(1, s, " ") Then
            ar = Split(s, " ")
            For j = LBound(ar) To UBound(ar)
                If ar(j) Like "NN*#" Then
                    Debug.Print ar(j)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

**Output**

```
NN1
NN12
```

Comment: I see where you are going but that just means i will need to loop it. I hoped there would be an option to use something like a input mask to avoid that.

I could just create a loop where variable I goes from 0 to 99 and use the instr function to look for "NN" & I. 
The problem is that this is already inside a loop that goes over rows. So if it needs to go over 100 rows and it needs to loop a 100 times for each row it needs to do 10 000 loops in total.

Comment: that loop is an example for the array. You can use it as `If Range("B" & row).Value Like "NN*#" Then`

Comment: That is exactly what I'm looking for, i will try it out and see if I get it going

Comment: Further information to help with future endeavors, @RobinOvaere, here is a list of wildcards: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx

Comment: I don't get it working. The Like wil evaluate in to a boolean true or false. I can use If Range("B" & row).Value Like "NN*#"  but that will only tell me if "NN*#" is in the that range. I need to know it's location so i can extract it. That is also the reason i want to use InStr, it gives me back the number where the to search string is so i can extract it with other functions as Left() or Right(). So i would need to use like this InStr(CStr(Range("B" & row).Value), Like "*NN*#") but offcoarse that trows an error

Comment: @RobinOvaere: Now since you made it clear, you will have to use the above approach but will have to club it with `Split`. Will the format always be like `XXXXX NN??? XXXXX`? i.e there will be a space before and after the `nn???`?

Answer (score 0):

Could this function work for you?

```
If IsNumeric(Right(Range("B" & row).Value, 1)) Then
    MsgBox "It ends with a Number."
Else
    MsgBox "It does not end with a Number."
End If
```

Comment: I'm afraid not. I'm searching a string in a long lenght string. Somewhere in that string (not know where it will be) there will be "NN5" for example. The question is not if NN will end with a number, it always does but how do I let it search for a string that ends with any number. I could just search for "NN" but then I risk it will return false possitives as the string "NN" can also exist in a word.

And PS: if you want to test the if the last character is a number use Right, not Left ;)

Comment: Yes it is Right sorry ! I was being very quick.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, simple looping could help:

```
Sub SearchNum()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim strSource As String
    Dim boolNumFound As Boolean

    'Found flag
    numFound = False

    'Put source string to variable
    '(put here your range address)
    strSource = Range("B1").Value

    'Loop through your number range
    For i = 0 To 99
        If InStr(1, strSource, "text" & i) Then
            numFound = True
            MsgBox "text" & i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: It would work but it is wasting resources, and like i mentioned in onther comment I'm already in a big loop that is going over rows. If I have 100 rows it will create 100 loops with each loop a 100 loops inside it so a total of 10000 loops. Also don't forget this is VBA, it is not as fast in executing as a normal program language.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue yesterday.  I took the answer given to me and edited it to fit your issue, but I can't take 100% credit :-p.  I believe this will get you what you're looking for.

```
    sub test()

    Dim sWords() As String
    Dim s As Variant
    Dim sResult As String


      sWords = Split(ActiveCell.Value, " ")
      For Each s In sWords
        If Left$(s, 2) = "NN" Then
            sResult = sResult & s
            msgbox sResult
            sResult = ""
        End if
      Next s

      end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will run a bit faster than the other solutions provided.
This is case-insensitive as written but removing the vbTextCompare would make it case-sensitive. I've tested this, the code works.

```
Function nnNumeric(ByVal textIn As String, Optional ByVal startPos As Long = 1) As Long
    'searches textIn for NN followed by a number; e.g. NN0, NN1, NN2, etc.
    'returns the position when found, otherwise returns #VALUE! error
    Dim i As Long
    i = InStr(startPos, textIn, "NN", vbTextCompare) 'remove vbTextCompare to make this case-sensitive
    Do While i > 0
        If IsNumeric(Mid(textIn, i + 2, 1)) Then
            nnNumeric = i
            Exit Function
        End If
        i = InStr(i + 1, textIn, "NN", vbTextCompare) 'remove vbTextCompare to make this case-sensitive
    Loop
    nnNumeric = CVErr(xlErrValue) '#VALUE! error
End Function
```